# Reset array keys in multidimensional array, recursive, by reference

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to reset keys in a big, multidimensional array. I already found a solution which is actually work:

```
$fix_keys = function(array $array) use (&$fix_keys)
{
    foreach($array as $k => $val)
    {
        if (is_array($val))
        {
            $array[$k] = $fix_keys($val);
        }
    }
    return array_values($array);
};
```

and the problem is, if I pass big arrays to it, it becomes slow and memory consuming. What about refactoring with working references:

```
$fix_keys = function(array &$array) use (&$fix_keys)
{
    foreach($array as $k => &$val)
    {
        if (is_array($val))
        {
            $array[$k] = $fix_keys($val);
        }
    }
    unset($val);
    $array = array_values($array);
};
```

but it messed up the array, all I get is `[0] => null`. What is wrong?

Edit: so input data:

```
$a = [
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,
    'c' => [
        'aa' => 11,
        'bb' => [
            'ccc' => 1
        ],
        'cc' => 33
    ]
];
```

and I want to have:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(11)
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(1)
    }
    [2]=>
    int(33)
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some input along with expected output

Answer (score 2):

If memory is an issue you can try using [`yield`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php). I'm not sure if this fits your needs, but here it is:

```
function reduce($array){
  foreach($array as $key => $value){
    if(is_array($value)){
      reduce($value);
    }
  }

  yield array_values($array);
}
```

---

You can also use [`send`](http://php.net/manual/ro/generator.send.php) if you need to apply some logic to the generator.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
$fix_keys = function(array &$array) use (&$fix_keys)
{
    foreach(array_keys($array) as $k)
    {
        if (is_array($array[$k]))
        {
            $fix_keys($array[$k]);
        }
    }
    $array = array_values($array);
};
```